# cocos2d multitouch for CCMotionStreak or Particle system

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, multi-touch

i want to enable multitouch for my game. but i don't know how to implement the multitouch version of CCMotionStreak. every time i touch 2 points with 2 fingers, there shows up a ribbon in between. what i want is one ribbon for each finger. 
i would be better if i can do it in Particle system, but basically i'm facing the same problem. 
anyone have done that before? just like fruit ninja.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a CCMotionStreak node for each touch.

For example:

```
-(void)createMotionStreak:(NSInteger)touchHash
{
    CCMotionStreak* streak = [CCMotionStreak streakWithFade:1.7f minSeg:10 image:@"arrow.png" width:32 length:32 color:ccc4(255, 0, 255, 255)];
    [self addChild:streak z:5 tag:touchHash];
}

-(void)removeMotionStreak:(NSInteger)touchHash
{
    [self removeChildByTag:touchHash cleanup:YES];
}

-(CCMotionStreak*)getMotionStreak:(NSInteger)touchHash
{
    CCNode* node = [self getChildByTag:touchHash];
    if(![node isKindOfClass:[CCMotionStreak class]]) {
        [self createMotionStreak:touchHash];
    }
    return (CCMotionStreak*)node;
}

-(void) addMotionStreakPoint:(CGPoint)point on:(NSInteger)touchHash
{
    CCMotionStreak* streak = [self getMotionStreak:touchHash];
    [streak.ribbon addPointAt:point width:32];
}

-(CGPoint)locationFromTouch:(UITouch*)touch
{
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    return [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:touchLocation];
}

-(void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSEnumerator* enumerator = [touches objectEnumerator];
    UITouch* oneTouch = nil;
    while (oneTouch = [enumerator nextObject]) {
        [self addMotionStreakPoint:[self locationFromTouch:oneTouch] on:oneTouch.hash];
    }
}

-(void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSEnumerator* enumerator = [touches objectEnumerator];
    UITouch* oneTouch = nil;
    while (oneTouch = [enumerator nextObject]) {
        [self removeMotionStreak:oneTouch.hash];
    }
}
```